# Incorporating a LOOP into a SQL

Tags: postgresql, loops, variables

I am fairly new at SQL and have not incorporated a Loop into a SQL statement previously. This SQL query from elan.elig returns data as shown in the grid below.

```
select  (extract(year from  age(case when terminationdate is null then 
CURRENT_DATE else terminationdate END ,effectivedate ))) *12 +
(extract(month from  age(case when terminationdate is null then 
CURRENT_DATE else terminationdate END ,effectivedate ))  +1)
as "mbrmonths" ,effectivedate
from elan.elig
```

```
Mbr Months  Effective Date
1   10/1/2018
10  11/1/2018
2   11/1/2018
8   11/1/2018
8   11/1/2018
8   11/1/2018
2   11/1/2018
2   11/1/2018
7   11/1/2018
```

For each row from the query I need to execute the subsequent LOOP that spreads the memberMonth counts into the Year/Month buckets. The following Do LOOP does exactly this. I have been trying for some time now to determine how to incorporate the Loop into the SQL statement so that for each row read, it will pass the two variables and execute the Loop and then read the next row and continue on..

```
DO $$
declare 
nbr_mem_months integer=5;
effectivedate date ='20190401';
ym char(6) =to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
begin
for r in 1..nbr_mem_months loop
update elan.pmpm set mbrmonths=mbrmonths+1 where yyyyymm=ym;
effectivedate=effectivedate + interval '1 month';
ym=to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

PMPM Buckets

```
yyyymm  mbrmonths
201901  0
201902  0
201903  0
201904  1
201905  1
201906  1
201907  1
201908  1
201909  0
201910  0
201911  0

CREATE FUNCTION "UpdatePMPM"() RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    nbr_mem_months NUMERIC;
    effectivedate date;
    ym char(6);
BEGIN
        LOOP
            ym=to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
            nbr_mem_months=5;
            UPDATE elan.pmpm set mbrmonths=mbrmonths+1 where yyyyymm=ym;
         
            effectivedate=effectivedate + interval '1 month';
        END LOOP;
    RETURN TRUE;
END
$$;



*Response from the Select statement:

ERROR:  function public.UpdatePMPM(integer, date, text) does not exist

Select public."UpdatePMPM"(5,cast('20190101' as date),cast('...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
```

Comment: You can't SQL does not have `LOOP`.  You will need to create a 'permanent' function(not `DO`) that does what you want.

Comment: How can I convert the DO Loop into a function, any help?

Comment: I'm heading out the door so I can't provide an example. The information you need though is found here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). That is the procedural language you are using in the `DO`. You just need to wrap it in a `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...`.

Comment: You can cross join to a `generate_series()` function, Something like `select ...
from elan.elig cross join generate_series(effectivedate, coalesce(terminationdate, current_date), interval '1 month')`

Comment: Add the function definition and error to your question as formatted code.

Comment: I made an attempt at the Function to replicate my DO LOOP from above. It compiles but does not execute. The Code and the results from the select statement are posted at the bottom of my original question aove.

Comment: `that spreads the memberMonth counts into the Year/Month buckets.` <<- it is not clear what you are trying to do. (but I still don't think you need a loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is calling the function with arguments but not specifying any when creating the function. So you need something like(not tested):

```
CREATE FUNCTION "UpdatePMPM"(nbr_mem_months integer, effectivdate date, some_arg varchar) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ym varchar := to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
BEGIN
        FOR r IN  1..nbr_mem_months LOOP
            
            UPDATE elan.pmpm set mbrmonths = mbrmonths+1 where yyyyymm = ym;
            effectivedate = effectivedate + interval '1 month';
            ym=to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$$;
```

From the error it is not clear what the third argument is supposed to be, so that will clarification from you.