# Calling a Function from SQL

Tags: postgresql, function

This is my Function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION "UpdatePMPM"(nbr_mem_months integer, effectivedate date) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ym varchar := to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
BEGIN
        FOR r IN  1..nbr_mem_months LOOP           
            UPDATE elan.pmpm set mbrmonths = mbrmonths+1 where yyyyymm = ym;
            effectivedate = effectivedate + interval '1 month';
            ym=to_char(effectivedate,'YYYYMM');
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$$;
```

and when I call it manually from pgAdmin client it works perfectly.

```
Select public."UpdatePMPM"(5, '2016-04-01')
```

However, I am getting an error when calling it from within a SQL query:

```
select  cast((extract(year from  age(case when terminationdate is null then 
CURRENT_DATE else terminationdate END ,effectivedate ))) *12 +
(extract(month from  age(case when terminationdate is null then 
CURRENT_DATE else terminationdate END ,effectivedate ))  +1) as integer)
as "mbrmonths" ,effectivedate ,public."UpdatePMPM"(mbrmonths, effectivedate)
from elan.elig
order by 1
```

***ERROR:  column "mbrmonths" does not exist
LINE 5: ...s "mbrmonths" ,effectivedate ,public."UpdatePMPM"(mbrmonths,...***

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function does not return anything to begin with. Second its action is to update a table so it does not make sense to call it a query anyway. You need to explain what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: is 'mbrmonths'  even accessible within the select? Try putting the cast statement in as the first parameter of the function instead of mbrmonths

Comment: The Outer SQL Statement run against the Eligibility Table (elig) and each record return a Start Date (effectivedate) and an End Date (terminationdate). For each record, I need to record in the Member Month Bucket file (elan.pmpm) an increment of 1 for each month the person is effective. i.e. If the Start Date is 2019-01-01 and the term date is 2019-04-30, then each of the member buckets in that range will get an increment of 1. So bucket  201901, 201902, 201903, and 201904 each get 1 added to their bucket totals.

Comment: As has been mentioned in [a comment on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851706/incorporating-a-loop-into-a-sql#comment121683187_68851706), you shouldn't be using a function with a loop here anyway. Use a single `UPDATE` statement, with a query using `generate_series` that tells it which rows to update.

Comment: Todd, you solved it! Thx Could you place your answer as a solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in the `SELECT` list to reference another column of the same list.

Either repeat the expression or use a subquery:

```
SELECT mbrmonths,
       effectivedate,
       public."UpdatePMPM"(mbrmonths, effectivedate)
FROM (select cast(
                (extract(year from age(case when terminationdate is null
                                            then CURRENT_DATE
                                            else terminationdate
                                       END,
                                       effectivedate)
                )) *12 +
                (extract(month from age(case when terminationdate is null
                                             then CURRENT_DATE
                                             else terminationdate
                                       END,
                                       effectivedate
                ))  +1
                as integer) as "mbrmonths",
             effectivedate,
      from elan.elig) AS subq
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of second argument is text, not date.

The Correct call is

```sql
Select public."UpdatePMPM"(5, '2016-04-01'::date)
```

Comment: The function argument is declared as a `date` so `'2016-04-01'` will be implicitly cast to a date, you don't need the explicit cast.